# Which is better, most important or the most important

Tags: word-usage, definite-article, superlatives

> A-1) What is most important to me in life is love.
> A-2) What is the most important to me in life is love.

> B-1) Love is most important in life.
> B-2) Love is the most important in life.

Are they all fine sentences? If not, please tell me which one is wrong and why.

Comment: IMHO, B2 isn't correct.  You need a noun if you want to use "the".  For example: "Love is the most important **thing** in life".

Answer (score 1):

"The" is an article. Articles apply to nouns. So if you have some noun that "important" is modifying, such as "Love is the most important thing", then "the" is appropriate. Sometimes the noun is omitted but understood. For instance, in the sentence "Of all the things in life, love is the most important", it's understood that "important" refers back to the noun "thing".